# BeautifulSoup: Striping an html element from files in a directory and writing the contents to a file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to open all the html files in a directory (so far so good), locate the footer element in each one (also good), remove the footers (no dice), and then write the results back out as html files without footers (also no dice).

Here is what I have got:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from os import listdir
from os import chdir

def main():
    # move into the nohead directory
    chdir('nohead')

    # get a list of the files in nohead
    filenames=listdir('.')


    for files in filenames:              
        soup = BeautifulSoup (open(files))
        bottom = soup.findAll("footer")  
            nothing = ""
            bottom.replaceWith(nothing)
    # and then I'd like to save each separate html file with its <footer> removed

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

which gives me the following error:

```
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replaceWith'
```

I have also tried

```
  for files in filenames:                       
      soup = BeautifulSoup (open(files, "w+"))  
      bottom = soup.findAll("footer")           
      decompose(bottom)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
    NameError: global name 'decompose' is not defined
```

I'd be glad of a BeautifulSoup3 or bs4 solution to this problem, especially if there's a way to save each html file as a separate file with its footer removed.

Comment: Yep, `bottom` is  a list (there's a list for each html file.  Each list only has one item in it: the complete `<footer>` element)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change as -

```
for files in filenames:              
    soup = BeautifulSoup (open(files))
    bottom = soup.findAll("footer")
    for single_footer in bottom:
        single_footer.decompose()
        #Then save
```

What about using `os.walk`-traverse a directory and change all the files have footer as below-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os

input_dir = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test"

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for single_file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root,single_file),'r+') as inpt:
            soup = bs(inpt.read(),'lxml')
            if len(soup.findAll('footer'))>0:
                for footer in soup.findAll('footer'):
                    footer.decompose()
                inpt.seek(0)#rewind
                inpt.write(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a tag in BeautifulSoup you should use decompose. In your case it should be:

```
import codecs
for files in filenames:              
    soup = BeautifulSoup (open(files))
    soup.footer.decompose()
    f=codecs.open("abc1.html", mode="w", encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(soup.prettify())
    f.close()
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose

Comment: decompose looks so promising, but I'm getting a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'` and when I `print type(soup)` I see that BeautifulSoup turns `files` from a string to `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` which I then can't use decompose on. Is there a way to make sure  that `soup = BeautifulSoup (open(files))` keeps `files` a string?

Comment: @CLKC Why would type(soup) return string?  In this statement soup = BeautifulSoup (open(files)), you are creating a BeautifulSoup object by calling its constructor and BeautifulSoup class supports decompose method. You should go through the documentation once.